# Unable in fetching user related data in php mysqli

Tags: php

i want to display all member names with their all transcation amount calculated and displayed besides them. like:- i have 4 members and some of them has 3 transcation some of them has 10 transcation and i want this result to be displayed as mr. XYZ  Transcation AMount Rs 5089 and so on

Comment: Please be specific with your question and if you can share what you have achieved.

- Your table structure.

Comment: Please vote if you found the answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`. For example:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("
  SELECT m.member_name, SUM(t.member_transaction)
  FROM members m, transactions t
  WHERE m.id = t.member_id
  GROUP BY member_name
  ORDER BY member_name
");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i forget to mention that members details and transcation details both are in different tables

Comment: Then you will need to "join" the tables together using a column. To learn more visit [MySQL Tutorial - JOIN Tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx). This web site will help you learn all of the basic SQL statements you need to accomplish what you are seeking.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your question.